# Mediarecorder.start() not working on Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

I have been encountering a strange problem while writing a web app. The purpose of this web app is to record about 10 seconds of video every few seconds from the device web cam and upload it to a server. The web app used MediaRecorder API as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API) . I am able to record video using firefox browser on a desktop. However, when i make my web app run on Firefox Beta or Firefox for Android, the Mediarecorder.state shows 'recording' while i get data.size = 0 bytes.

Below is the code snippet which shows how the recording is done:

```
timerId = setInterval(function () {

                    recorder.start(length);

                    console.log(recorder.state);

                    // console.log(timerId);

                    recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {

                        if (recorder.state == 'recording' && navigator.onLine == true) {
                            //var blob = new window.Blob([event.data], {
                            //    type: 'video/mp4'
                            //});

                            var blob = new window.Blob([event.data]);

                            // use the created blob

                            console.log('data size: ' + blob.size);

                            counter++;

                            var formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append("blob", blob, "video" + counter);
                            formData.append("deviceid", deviceId);
                            formData.append("seqid", counter);

                            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                                    console.log(request.responseText);
                                }
                            }
                            request.open("POST", "/Device/Upload3", true);
                            request.send(formData);

                            if (recorder != null)
                                recorder.stop();
                        }
                    };

                }, 30000);
```

I have tried setting the cache permissions in about:config too but no luck. Kindly help me figure this out.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: I would guess that the media recorder functionality is simply not supported for the particular platform or device? If I were you I would try with a different version of android on a different device.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I found out the answer and sharing it so that it benefits everyone - Currently the MediaRecorder API does not support video recording on Firefox for Android.  [image: Snapshot showing the current support for MediaRecorder on Mobile]I found it on the support page at MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)